# django - get list of objects by filtering a list of objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I am creating a user activity streams.

models for activity:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

model for Relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', 
                                           symmetrical=False, 
                                           related_name='related_to')
RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
    (RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 'Following'),
    (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='to_people')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)  

def get_relationships(self, status):
    return self.relationships.filter(
        to_people__status=status, 
        to_people__from_person=self)

def get_following(self):
    return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)
```

In the views:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        userP = Person.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        userP = userP[0]
        following = userP.get_following()
        activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=following)
        if request.POST:
            form = StatusForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    status = form.save(commit=False)
                    status.user = user
                    status.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Scenario

- user is following user2 and user3
- user2 is following user and user3
- user3 is following user and user2

Since I am filtering activities with `actor=user` and not `actor=userP` (which is an object of type `user.person`). How will I get a list of `user object` from the list `get_following()` method and not of `user.person object`.

I can however loop through each of the `following` like so:

```
    following = userP.get_following()
    users = []
    for u in following:
        users.append(u.user)
    users.append(user)
    activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=users)
```

But I am hoping that there will be another better way to do it?

Please guide me. Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In case you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can checkout [`django-activity-stream`](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the queryset's [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method:

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=
                                     following.values_list('user', flat=True))
```

If you want to add another user to actors list then you have to convert `valies_list` from queryset to regular python list:

```
actors = list(following.values_list('user', flat=True)) + [user.id]
activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=actors)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for checking this question! And its working correctly. I just want to add (`append`) the user too (please check the views), so as to get the activities of the user and its following user.  How do I add the user too in the list of activities.

Comment: I tried doing this: `>>> activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=following.values_list('user',
flat=True)).append(user)` but its giving me an error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so so much! Working great. If you are interested please have a look at this question, I am stuck in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156796/django-filter-by-distinct-fields-of-a-model-class/28157544?noredirect=1#comment44689563_28157544

Comment: @catavaran Would you please give a word here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665037/concurrency-advanced-python-and-interaction-with-different-objects