# django - getting the requested user object in the template through models method

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Please have a look at this code:

models:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Activity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities'
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ("%s %s") % (self.actor.username, self.action)

    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = '%s_activity.html' %(self.content_type.name)
        return render_to_string(template_name, {
            'object':self.content_object,
            'actor':self.actor,
            'action':self.action,
        })
```

template:

```
<div class="user_activity">
    <p><a href="/{{ actor.username }}/">{{ actor.username }}</a> {{ action }} <a href="/{{ object.content_object.user.username }}/">{{ object.content_object.user.username }}</a> status</p>

    <p>{{ object.content_object.body }}</p>
    <p>{{ object.content_object.pub_date }}</p>

    {% if object.content_object.image %}
        <div class="activity_img_wrapper">
            <p><img src="/media/{{ object.content_object.image }}"/></p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**Question**

How do I get the requested user's username for the above template (request.user). I did like this, but it didn't help :

```
<div class="user_activity">
    <p>
        {% if user.username == actor.username %}
            You
        {% else %}
            <a href="/{{ actor.username }}/">{{ actor.username }}</a>
        {% endif %}
        {{ action }}
        {% if user.username ==  object.content_object.user.username %}
            Your
        {% else %}
            <a href="/{{ object.content_object.user.username }}/">{{ object.content_object.user.username }}</a>
        {% endif %}
        status
    </p>
    <p>{{ object.content_object.body }}</p>
    <p>{{ object.content_object.pub_date }}</p>
    {% if object.content_object.image %}
        <div class="activity_img_wrapper">
            <p><img src="/media/{{ object.content_object.image }}"/></p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Please help me how to do it. I would really be grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: yes, i did so. But not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `RequestContext` object available in the `get_rendered_html()` method so you can't pass it as a `context_instance` argument of the `render_to_string()`.  This is why the `user` variable is not available in the template.

You should pass the `User` instance to `get_rendered_html()` method and propagate it to the template:

```
def get_rendered_html(self, user=None):
    template_name = '%s_activity.html' %(self.content_type.name)
    return render_to_string(template_name, {
        'object':self.content_object,
        'actor':self.actor,
        'action':self.action,
        'user':user,
    })
```

If you want to call this method from other template then the best option is to use [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
# app/templatetags/activity_tags.py
# and don't forget to create empty app/templatetags/__init__.py :-)
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_activity(context, activity):
    user = context['user']
    html = activity.get_rendered_html(user)
    return mark_safe(html)
```

And then load and use this tag library in your template:

```
{% load activity_tags %}
...
{% render_activity activity %}
```

Comment: I changed the method as you showed me. But I am getting error `global name 'user' is not defined`.

Comment: Note the second argument of the `get_rendered_html()`.  You have to call this method with current `User` instance.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you. In the method I added `user=None` and `user=user`. Now not getting any errors but the username is not changed by You.

Comment: You should change the code where you call this method.  Something like this: `html = activity.get_rendered_html(request.user)`

Comment: I am getting this error: `Could not parse the remainder: '(request.user)' from 'activity.get_rendered_html(request.user)'`

Comment: Seems like you call this method not from python code but from some template.  If yes then see updated answer.

Comment: Yes, seems like there's no other way than to use the template tags. And its working. Thank you so much for your help! You really are a life saver. Can you please have a look at this question too if possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148883/django-get-list-of-objects-by-filtering-a-list-of-objects