# django - Filter by distinct fields of a model class

Tags: django, django-views

I have a model for activities of users:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Activity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities'
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ("%s %s") % (self.actor.username, self.action)
```

views:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        userP = Person.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        userP = userP[0]
        following = userP.get_following()
        users = []
        actors = list(following.values_list('user', flat=True)) + [user.id]
        activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=actors)
```

**update**

Suppose 3 users likes the same status and user3 was the last one to like that status. Now that will create 3 activities saying "User1 liked status", "User2 liked status", "User3 liked status". What I want is only get one activity per status that is the most recent one. So in this case it would be "User3 liked status".

status model:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=PRIVACY, default='F')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    hearts = generic.GenericRelation(Heart, null=True, blank=True)

class Heart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

**Update**

This is signals.py to create activity per object (heart or status):

```
def create_activity_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
        if ctype.name == 'Status':
            action = ' shared '

            activity = Activity.objects.get_or_create(
                actor = instance.user,
                action = action,
                content_type = ctype,
                object_id = instance.id,
                pub_date = instance.pub_date
            )

        if ctype.name == 'Heart':
            action = ' gave heart to '

            activity = Activity.objects.get_or_create(
                actor = instance.user,
                action = action,
                content_type = ctype,
                object_id = instance.id,
                pub_date = instance.pub_date
            )

for modelname in [Status, Heart]:
    post_save.connect(create_activity_item, sender=modelname,
                  dispatch_uid="create_activity_item")
```

Comment: what db are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=users).distinct('content_type', 'object_id', 'action')
```

If your database does not support `DISTINCT ON` queries, you can do the query then manually run through the objects finding distinct values:

```
unique_activities = []
activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=users)
for activity in activities:
    unseen = True
    for unique_activity in unique_activities:
        if (activity.action == unique_activity.action and activity.content_type == unique_activity.content_type and activity.object_id == unique_activity.object_id):
            unseen = False
            break
    if unseen:
         unique_activities.append(activity)

print unique_activities
```

Comment: Really? And `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=users)` gives you activities?

Comment: I changed it to specify `content_type` and `object_id` as separate fields to be distinct on (rather than the GenericForeignKey).  Does it work now?

Comment: What does `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=users)` give you?

Comment: I checked the same thing in the shell, and when I try to get the `activities`, its showing me an error: `NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`.

Comment: `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=users)` gives me list of activities of `users`.

Comment: I am using sqlite for development, and I think `distinct()` is supported only in postgresql. Is there any other way?

Comment: I edited my answer to add a way of finding distinct results in Python rather than SQL.

Comment: Sorry, but its giving me all the activities now, and not distinct ones.

Comment: `unique_activities` is giving you all activities? Can you try printing out activity.action, activity.content_type, and activity.object_id for each to make sure it's really giving you duplicates?

Comment: Your method was right. The problem was in my elaboration of question. I am sorry for that. Please bear with me, Suppose 3 users like the same status, now that will create 3 activities saying "User1 liked status", "User2 liked status", "User3 liked status". What I want is only get one activity per status that is the most recent one. So in this case it would be "User3 liked status". I hope I was clear now.  I have added the status model too in the updates. Please ask if I you would want me to elaborate more. And I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Do you want only one activity per status, or one activity per status-action pair?  I.e., if User1 liked Status1, and User2 disliked Status1, do you want both or just the most recent one?

Comment: Yes, one activity per action of the status.

Comment: Assuming the status is what content_object points to, then the code in the answer should do that for you.  What does it give you when you print `unique_activities` after the loop?

Comment: It does give me unique activities, which are all the activities.... because the content objects which are the likes are not same. It should check with its related foreign key i guess.

Comment: Got it.  How are Status objects linked to activities?  Through Hearts?

Comment: No, activity of status is created independently whenever it is newly posted. And the activity of heart is created whenever someone likes an object that would be the status. I have updated with the `signals.py` which creates the activity.

Comment: It certainly looks like the content_objects in your example are Statuses (or Hearts).  So this code should only print out one activity per Status.  It should also print out activities that are linked to Hearts--is that the problem?

Comment: Yes. Because, if a status gets too many likes, there will be many activities regarding that single status in the templates. What I want is to make it like facebook home page, where they don't show all the activities of a photo liked or commented by, and only show one likes or comment per photo.

Comment: As this code is written, `unique_activities` will only include up to one "gave a heart to" and one "shared" action each for each status.  So I believe this already does exactly what you are requesting.  Have you looked at `unique_activities` and confirmed that it includes actions that it shouldn't? Can you paste what `unique_activities` is and what you want it to be?

Answer (score 1):

This will work only with PostgreSQL:

```
Activity.objects.order_by('action', 'content_type_id', 'object_id', '-pub_date').distinct('action', 'content_type_id', 'object_id').filter(actor__in=actors)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a `greatest-per-group` problem. Can you try this:

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(
    id__in=Activity.objects.values('content_type') \
        .annotate(max_id=Max('id')) \
        .values_list('max_id', flat=True) \
)
```